# Cypress - generate a token

Tags: cypress

I'm struggling to understand what is going wrong with the code below. I am attempting to use 4 params in the body to generate a token. I'm fairly certain it worked before , but now I get an error for the grant_type: 
error_description": "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.\r\nTrace ID: a1d...

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getToken', () => {
    cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://login.microsoftonli......./oauth2/v2.0/token',
        body: {
            grant_type: 'client_credentials',
            client_secret: 'o.ereerer....',
            client_id: '979455........',
            scope: 'https://btest.com/.default'
        },
    }).then((response) => {
        const access_token = response
        console.log('response', response)
    })
```

[Bad Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4T8D.png)

Comment: Can you add the entire error msg or screenshot?

Comment: Added a screenshot.

Comment: You're missing the closing parenthesis and bracket. Is that from the code or just a copy error?

Answer (score 0):

Upon further review, I determined the issue was that the request needed to be of a form data type. That got me further, but encountered a cors issue with the login.microsoftonline request, which I am currently tshooting. Thanks for the quick comments. I will consider this issue closed as posted.

Comment: What was the solution finally for the CORS issue?